# What is the melting point of diamond?

Tags: phase, elements, melting-point

Textbooks and the online reference differ about this and there are more than two answers.

Comment: Some additional information can be found [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/6834/) and the links within.

Comment: melting point of diamond is 3823K

Comment: I wish this question would include a question …

Comment: Liquid diamond certainly sounds cool. It even glows!

Answer (score 22):

Diamond (carbon) does not melt at 1 atm. It sublimes to vapor.

Using carbon's theoretical phase diagram below (from Wikimedia), "liquid diamond" could be achieved at about 10 GPa (99 thousand atmospheres) and 5000 K (4700 °C).

[image: phase diagram of carbon]

**Edit:**

In fact, heating up diamonds at 1 atm turns them into graphite first. Only further heating would cause sublimation, as expected by observing the phase diagram. Here's a video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7L7BV3IBfFA

Comment: It is 3783 K in reference books

Comment: Note that if heating it in the atmosphere, it will burn to carbon dioxide much before it sublimates to vapour carbon. HEATING DIAMONDS IS A BAD IDEA!

Comment: While I understand that the [phase diagram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Carbon_basic_phase_diagram.png) you're using is mainly focused on the high temperature and pressure region, I can't help but feel that the boundaries of the metastable region could use some fine-tuning. Taken literally, it seems to be claiming that diamond isn't (meta)stable at room temperature and pressure(!). (Apparently, the actual [thermal stability limit of diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_properties_of_diamond#Thermal_stability) at low pressure is about 2000 K.)

Comment: Definition (wikipedia): Sublimation - is the phase transition of a substance directly from the solid to the gas phase without passing through the intermediate liquid phase.

Comment: Minor point:  The quoted temperature conversion is mathematically correct, but in all probability no more than two digits are significant.  Thus $5000 K=4700°C$.